# How can I make my toggle nav button work in BS5?

Tags: php, toggle, navbar, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am triying to figure out why my toggle icon is not showed,and why the nav bar is not showing the menu elements when I use the mobile view.
I have created a border to see if the icon is there,and I can see the red frame,but when I click on it,does not work,and is not showing any content.
Can someone please help me.

This is my code so far:

```
<header>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="intro-video">
        <video class="videobaner" id="video" preload autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
            <source src="img/background.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            <source type="video/webm" src="img/theremin2.mp4"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="width:auto;background-color:black;">
        <div class="container-fluid mb-2 mt-2">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse flex justify-content-md-center">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto align-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="music.php"> MUSIC </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="events.php"> EVENTS </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">FEATURED</a>
                             <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="arts.php">ARTS</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="blog.php">BLOG</a></li>
                             </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SUBSCRIPTION </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-md-fill flex-shrink-1 d-md-none">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapsenav">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"style="color:white;border:2px solid red;"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
          
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

<style>

header .jumbotron{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 40rem;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }

  nav {
  opacity: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  /* position: relative; */
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
    left: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom:0px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: white !important;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    height:30px;
  }
 nav ul {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:20px 35px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .450rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white!important;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px 35px;
    height: 1%;
  }
  nav ul a {

    height:35px;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:16px 32px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    color:white !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;

  }
  nav ul a:hover {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white!important;

  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap5 uses `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` for the toggler. Change

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapsenav">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"style="color:white;border:2px solid red;"></span>
</button>
```

to

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".collapsenav">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white;border:2px solid red;"></span>
</button>
```

More on the Bootstrap5 [toggler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#toggler)

Comment: I tried it,but still not working

Comment: `data-bs-target=".collapsenav"` There is no element with a class `collapsenav` in your code. Read the documentation I posted and make sure you have an element to be collapsed

Comment: thank you very much Brombeer,gonna read the documentation,I am really struggled with this,and right now I cant function clearly

Comment: No problem, take a little break, do something else, get back to the problem later. Feel free to ask if you're stuck

Comment: Your comment is everything. Thank you very much.